# Query Contact By (Normalized) Phone Number

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-cursor

I'm really surprised I can't find the answer anywhere. So here's the problem.

```
ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();

String[] columns = new String[]{Phone.CONTACT_ID, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, Phone.NUMBER };
String where = Phone.NUMBER+"=?";
String[] params = new String[] {"777 777 7777"};
Cursor cursor = resolver.query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, columns, where, params, null);    

while (cursor.moveToNext()) { /* So on....*/
```

When the phone number in params is formated as "777 777 7777" I get no records. When it is "777-777-7777" it get records. Even worse still the TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER gives me the number as "7777777777". How do I query for this phone number? The docs say Phone.NUMBER is how the user ENTERED it. Well, that doesn't do me any good!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this :

```
 Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,Uri.encode(phoneNumber));        
 Cursor cs= context.getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME},null,null,null);

 if(cs.getCount()>0)
    contactName=cs.getString(cs.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));

cs.close();
```

**Edited (According to Your Comment)**

```
String phoneNumber = "777 777 7777"; 
Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(Phone.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));      
String[] columns = new String[]{Phone.CONTACT_ID, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, Phone.NUMBER };    
Cursor cursor = resolver.query(uri, columns, null, null, null);
```

Comment: thank you! I ended up going with this:
String phoneNumber = "777 777 7777";
  Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(Phone.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
  String[] columns = new String[]{Phone.CONTACT_ID, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, Phone.NUMBER };
  Cursor cursor = resolver.query(uri, columns, null, null, null);

Comment: Thank you. follow up question: This query is very slow taking 1300 milliseconds to execute in the emulator with 4 contacts. Do you know of any way to speed it up? I'm concerned when I hundreds of contacts.